# accessing struct massive in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uikit

I've created an collection view with `carName`'s there are 5 of them, after clicking for example `Mercedes`(one of the collection view's cell) I want to set label text its own values:`carModel` ( carName and carModel are both same struct properties ) in Table view which is already created by me, but I cant access `carModel` array

I tried for loop but it returns an error

```swift
for i in cars.carModel {
  lbl.text = cars.carModel[i]
}
```

any solution will be appericated

// data source file

```swift
struct Cars {
    let carName:String
    let carModel:[String]
}
let cars:[Cars] = [
    Cars(carName: "Mercedes", carModel: ["S Class","A Class", "B Class"]),
    Cars(carName: "BMW", carModel: ["X5","X6","X7"]),
    Cars(carName: "Ford", carModel: ["Fuison","Focus","Mustang"]),
    Cars(carName: "Toyota", carModel: ["Camry", "Corolla"]),
    Cars(carName: "Hyundai", carModel: ["Elantra"])
]
```

// table view cell file

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
    func configure(with cars:Cars){
            lbl.text = cars.carName
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

// mainviewcontroller

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    //@IBOutlet weak var tableView
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cars.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        cell?.setup(with: cars[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
}

extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: cars[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    }
```

Here's my simulator:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7OXR.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SnFG.png)

what I want:[expected result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLYxC.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you defined your `UITableViewDataSource` you set the number of rows in function method to return a constant (5). In `cellForRowAt` function you setup the cell with a `Cars` object.

I think you are mixing what data should be use for table view's datasource.

For collection view data source you have to:

- *Number of rows in section* function should return: `cars.count`
- *Cell for item at* function must configure CollectionViewCell with a `Cars` instance

I think all you are missing is saving which cell is being selected in collection view to use this to supply correct data to table view.

In collection view delegate when user taps on a cell you can either save the selected indexPath or `Cars` instance, this will be use by table view delegate. Let's call it `selectedCar`.

Then for table view data source you have to:

- *Number of rows in section* function should return: `selectedCar.carModel.count`
- *Cell for item at* function must configure TableViewCell with a `CarModel` instance (which is a `String`)

I created a small project in [Github](https://github.com/acyrman/StackOverflow69486550) as a sample, is working as expected. Check it out. Hope this helps you. [Sample video](https://youtu.be/ROGO-GNm1Bo) in Youtube.

**Note**: Setting datasource and delegate for tableView or collectionView in ViewController is not the best way to organize code but for sample code is ok.